# jsPlumb & bootstrap taps: Connections are not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsplumb

**The Problem:** Im currently building a process simulation. I ve 2 bootstrap taps, one contains an editor(which works fine), the otherone is used to display the content during simulation. JsPlumb is used in order to display different simulation objects. The Problem is that the connections between these objects arent correctly displayed if the tap is switched from the editor to the simulation. They "snap" into the right position after an element is dragged, but I want them to render correctly on the tap switch.
Here is a fiddle: [Problem fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hducj3Lt/)

Code:

html:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#editor" data-target="#editor" data-toggle="tab">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>Editor
            </a> 
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#display" data-target="#display" data-toggle="tab" id="testlink">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span> Simulation
            </a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="editor"> </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="display">
       <div class="container center-block content">
         <div id="test1" class="window">
            a
         </div>

         <div id="test2" class="window">
           b
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
   jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $('#display');


   jsPlumb.connect({
     source: $('#test1'),
     target: $('#test2'),
     anchor: "Continuous",
     endpoint: "Blank",
     detachable: false

   });

   jsPlumb.draggable($(".window"));

 });
```

**What I know:** The problem is directly related to the fact that the tab content is not displayed on load, since placing the test divs into the editor tap (which is the active one on load) resolves the problem. [fiddle: placing divs in aktive tab](https://jsfiddle.net/hke6rym7/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an optimal solution but this works:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'display-tab') {
    jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
    redrawEveryConnection();
  }
});
```

This code removes every connection on a tab switch to the simulation and calls the redraw function, which has to be implemented depending on the situation (the start and endpoints ve to be saved somewehere e.g. server).